# c++ std error in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, program-entry-point

I just started c++

here is the code for a basic main declaration and based on many tutorails I have found, also contains the code to print hello world to console

```
// TestApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

I am using VS 2012 Express, I dont know which compiler but the "cout" is underlined in red

**errors are as follows:**

> error C2039 'cout': is nit a member of 'std'    ln 9   col 1 error
>   C2065 : undeclared identifier             ln 9   col 1 IntelliSense:
>   namespace "std" has no member "cout"   ln 9   col 7

I do not understand why it is giving an error, could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is telling you that `std::cout` hasn't yet been declared anywhere in this translation unit. You can't use something if it hasn't been declared. `std::cout` is declared in the C++ standard library `<iostream>` header:

```
#include <iostream>
```

If you receive a similar error in the future and you need to know which header to include, look up some documentation for the particular function/type you want to use. For example, if you look at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), it states "Defined in header `<iostream>`".

Comment: thank you for your very insightful response, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Include below code :

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: @chris Oh yes.. let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

should be fine now